# Is there a word for the opposite of localization in ring theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In ring theory, localization roughly speaking is making a ring more like a field. Is there a name for the opposite process? Say removing all powers of 2 from the denominator from Q as a delocalization of 2?

Comment: Well, that would be a subring...

Comment: So for a ring $Q$ and an invertible element $f\in Q$, you want the "canonical" (minimal?) subring $R\subset Q$ such that $R_f=Q$?

Comment: You seem to want a term for a process that would take as input a ring, and then return a ring that where some of the elements that were units are no longer units. This is going to be hard, and if it exists it wouldn't be well-behaved because ring homomorphisms take units to units (assuming we have and fix 1), so while adding them isn't so bad, removing them is another matter. As Arturo pointed out, you can just take a subring that doesn't have inverses for the things you don't want to be units anymore, but that's about all you can do...